# Как я через telebot могу принимать заявку в приватную группу

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть задача что бы когда пользователь нажимал, подать заявку на вступление, ему в личку писал бот моей капчей, после если всё успешно бот принимает заявку на сообщение. Хотелось бы видеть реализацию через какие декораторы прослушиваются данные события.

Если что я про системные заявки на вступление, своих не надо:
Капча так же уже реализована, просто надо показать методы которые помогут отслеживать данные моменты.

[фото как выглядит](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewl70.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я думаю, что стоит почитать тут -> https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.chatjoinrequest.html#telegram.ChatJoinRequest и тут -> https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.chatjoinrequesthandler.html

Comment: Правда чот я сам не догоняю как сделать `ChatJoinRequestHandler` используя `telebot`